# How to Position Symfony2 Forms Error at proper place?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am using Symfony form in my project, here is the code :

**Form** :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', 'text', array('required' => true, 'error_bubbling' => true));
    $builder->add('email', 'email', array('required' => true, 'error_bubbling' => true));
    $builder->add('message', 'textarea', array('required' => true, 'error_bubbling' => true));
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    $constraintCollection = new Collection(array(
        'name' => new NotBlank(array("message" => "Please fill out Name field")),
        'email' => array(new Email(array("message" => "Invalid Email", "checkMX" => true)),
                         new NotBlank(array("message" => "Please fill out Email field"))),
        'message' => new NotBlank(array("message" => "Please fill out Message field"))
    ));

    return array(
        "validation_constraint" => $constraintCollection,
    );
}
```

**Template** (Twig) -

```
<form action="{{ path('somePath') }}" method="post">
        <p>Contact Us :</p>
          {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
        <p> {{ form_label(form.name, "Your Name") }}
            {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
        </p>
          {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
        <p> {{ form_label(form.email, "Your Email") }}
            {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
        </p>
          {{ form_errors(form.message) }}
        <p> {{ form_label(form.message, "Your Message") }}
            {{ form_widget(form.message) }}
        </p>
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    <div class="submit-button">
      <button class="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When i tried to submit the empty form it didn't show any error message, so i also added

`{{ form_errors(form) }}` after `<form>`, as i have seen it [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand).
But now it showing me form errors at Top position not to their respective fields.
Am i doing something wrong here?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the 'error_bubbling' => true option in your form definition. This option makes that any error on the field is "passed up" to the form, that is why you see the errors in form_errors(form) and not in form_errors(field)

Comment: It groups error messages at the higher form level, not leaving them appear on each concerned field..

Comment: I explained it in my answer: if you set error_bubbling to true, then any error produced in any field is "sent up" to the form.

Comment: Moreover, the `collection` form type has `error_bubbling` that defaults to `true` (insert snide comment here), so you have to override it.